# Is there a way to blacklist USB devices without unplugging?

Tags: usb

I'd like to prevent an USB device from registering (e.g. the internal Bluetooth hub). Is there a way to blacklist/disconnect USB devices without physically unplugging them?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps there's another approach

Comment: I'm trying to use an external Bluetooth dongle rather than the internal one, due to wifi-coexistance issues that are causing major interference problems.